For DOS calculation in vasp; should I use primitive unit cell or conventional unit cell?
I have observed that the Density of States (DOS) changes depending on whether a primitive or conventional unit cell is used for the calculation. This raises an important question: Which type of unit cell should be used when reporting DOS in a research article or, more generally, in scientific studies?

Please refer to this answer https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/13547/1554

It still does not answer the question though.

My answer there doesn't answer your question, but the question there does! The short answer is that it doesn't matter, the DOS should be identical to within an arbitrary multiplicative factor. You can choose to fix that factor by some other desired property, e.g. that the integrated DOS is the number of states computed, or normalise by atoms, or volume... but that's up to you.
